# Showing a subset is open

Tags: real-analysis

If $\beta$ > 0 and  T ⊆ $\mathbb{R}$ is an open set. Show that the subset $\beta$+T = {$\beta$+x | x ∈ T}
is open in R.

Can I assume that T is open and just choose epsilon as $\beta$ and the proof is done?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Is your definition of open set that each element of it has a ball of radius $\epsilon$ in it?  If so, if $T=(0,1)$ and $\beta=5$, then $\beta+T=(5,6)$, and $\beta$ is too big to serve as $\epsilon$

Comment: Nope. T is open iff for any x ∈ T, there is epsilon >0 such that (x-epsilon,x+epsilon) is a subset of T

Comment: that's the same thing

Comment: "Can I assume that T is open and just choose epsilon as β and the proof is done?"  No.  That's not really how the definition or proofs work at all.  Besides If $t\in T$ but $t < y; y \not \in T$ and $y-t < \beta$. then  $t+\beta \in T+\beta$ while $y + \beta\not \in T+ \beta$ but $t +\beta < y+ \beta < (t+\beta) + \beta$ so that just doesn't work at all.

Comment: by the way, the requirement $\beta>0$ seems unnecessary

Comment: But you have utterly no reason to assume that for any $x +\beta\in T$ that $((x+\beta)-\beta, (x+\beta)+\beta) = (x, x+ 2\beta) \subset T+\beta$.  Indeed if $(x-\beta, x+\beta)\not \subset T$ then $(x,x+2\beta) \not \subset \beta+ T$. And why would you think $(x-\beta, x+\beta) \subset T$?

Answer (score 1):

The function $f_x(t)=t-x$ ($x$ is fixed) is continuous. Thus, for any one set $U$, $f^{-1}_x(U)$ is open. Notice that $f^{-1}_x(U)=x+U$

This is based on the fact that a function $f$ (from a topological space to another one, but for now the real space suffices) is continuous if and only if the preimage $f^{-1}(U)=\{x: f(x)\in U\}$ is open for any open set $U$. If you have not sen this result, you may try to open in your setting by using $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$ balls.

Comment: I am not following

Comment: A function $f$ is continuous if and only if the preimage $f^{-1}(U)$ of any one set $U$ is open.

Comment: Obviously that is not something the OP has be taught yet.

Answer (score 0):

Since $T$ is open, for all $x\in T$ there is $\epsilon>0$ such that $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\subset T$.

Now take $y\in \beta+T$.  We wish to show that there is $\epsilon>0$ such that $(y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon)\subset \beta+T$.

Well, if $y\in\beta+T,$ then $y-\beta\in T$,

and, since $T$ is open, there is $\epsilon>0$ such that $(y-\beta-\epsilon,y-\beta+\epsilon)\subset T.$

Can you shown then that, for such $\epsilon$, $(y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon)\subset\beta+T$?

Answer (score 0):

You know that $T$ is open, so $\forall x \in T$, exists an $\epsilon >0 $ s.t. $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon) \subset T$.

Now, when you translate $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$ by $\beta$ you will end with $(x-\epsilon + \beta, x -\epsilon + \beta) \subset \beta + T$.

Answer (score 0):

If $w \in \beta + T$ then there must be an $x \in T$ so that $w= x +\beta$.

And because $x \in T$ there must be an $\epsilon$ so that $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon) \subset T$.

Just use the exact same $\epsilon$ and try to prove $(w-\epsilon, w+\epsilon)=((x+\beta)-\epsilon, (x+\beta)+\epsilon)\subset \beta + T$.

Note:  You *do* have to prove it.  You can't just state it.

But note:  If $y\in ((x+\beta)-\epsilon, (x+\beta)+\epsilon))$ then

$(x+\beta)-\epsilon < y < (x+\beta)+\epsilon$  which says what about $y-\beta$?  Can we claim $y -\beta \in T$? Why or why not?  What does that tell us about whether $y \in \beta+T$ or not?  Now that we've done that what do we need to do to prove $((x+\beta)-\epsilon, (x+\beta)+\epsilon)\in \beta + T$?